# Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

I am running following code

```
/*Fetchinch Last CustID from custMaster*/
int ID = 0;
try
{
     con.Open();
     da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select max(Id) from custMaster",con);
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     da.Fill(ds);
     for(int i=0;i<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++)
        ID=int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
     con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex) {}
finally 
{
     con.Close();
}
```

I am putting debugger from the first statement of try block and finding that error is coming when I am trying to open the connection.
Error Text:

> Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Connection String is:

> "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=E:\NewSoft\Database\TestApp.accdb;Integrated
>   Security=SSPI"

I am using oledb connections.

Comment: Doesn't that statement return a scalar instead of a datatable?

Comment: Error comming after con.open()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be the result of the error in your connection string. You should try to add

```
Persist Security Info=True;
```

Or you might have problems in your registry with your OLE DB provider, which must have OLEDB_SERVICES record. In the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID, find the CLSID of the OLE DB provider and add the following registry value:

```
Value Name: OLEDB_SERVICES
Data Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 0xFFFFFFFF
```

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269495 for more information

Comment: Do you have any idea how I am supposed to know the CLSID? I can't seem to find anything about this (your link is expired)

Comment: @Bassie I did a search for "Microsoft KB 269495" and found this link which appears to be an archived version of the KB document referenced. https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/269495

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue when opening a connection with the following connection string:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True
```

Changing `Integrated Security=True` to `Integrated Security=SSPI` in the connection string fixed the problem.

Comment: The OP is already using SSPI, so this clearly doesn’t answer the original question. Instead, you are posing a new question and answering it.

Answer (score 1):

For a similar problem connecting to a MS Access database, this exact error was generated for a wrong password set in the connection attribute of **Jet OLEDB:Database Password=**

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem but found out to be special characters used in the password.

So, I changed the Access file password and replaced **Jet OLEDB:Database Password=** with the updated one and it solved the issue.