# Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value,

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to connect to an Access database from C#, but it's returning an error.

I'm trying to resolve by following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129744/multiple-step-ole-db-operation-generated-errors-check-each-ole-db-status-value), but it is not working.

Can you tell me where I went wrong?

```
connection_string =@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password=pass@word1;Location=C:\Users\manoj\Documents\manoj\Databases\college.accdb;Persist Security Info=True;";
```

The error is:

> Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Comment: This may help:http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Comment: hi kareem, I tried that also, it's returning same error

Comment: If you like to email me your database I could create a correct string for you. I have MS-Access 2007

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because `Location=` is not a valid parameter for an OLEDB connection string. You need to use `Data Source=` instead, as in

```
... ;Data Source=C:\Users\manoj\Documents\manoj\Databases\college.accdb; ...
```