# SSIS Access DB - Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors

Tags: ms-access, ssis, oledb, oledbconnection

**Problem:** In SSIS (BIDS 2008) even the most simple Execute SQL Task against an Access Database produces the following Warning:

> Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Many posts point to parameter mapping as the culprit, however, I am receiving this Warning on even the most basic SELECT statement (no parameter mapping involved).

Here are the SSIS connection settings for the Access DB:

[image: Connection Manager - Connection]
[image: Connection Manager - All]

Here is the Execute SQL Task that generates the warning:

[image: Control Flow]
[image: Execute SQL Task]

**Note 1:** *Two* identical "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors" Warnings are generated for *each* Execute SQL Task.

**Note 2:** Despite the Warning, the Execute SQL Task always completes successfully.

**Bottom Line:** What is causing two "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors" Warnings to be generated for each Execute SQL Task and how can I correct the issue?

Comment: Tried changing `Persist Security Info = True` as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129744/multiple-step-ole-db-operation-generated-errors-check-each-ole-db-status-value) but unfortunately that had no effect.

Comment: In the Progress tab, the two identical warnings come after _"Validation is completed"_ and before the _"Progress: Executing query ... 100 percent complete"_ result